# Get Table Status for custom WordPress DB

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to get the next auto_increment number for an insert value to a custom WordPress database table.

My code is the following:

```
$result = $wpdb->prepare("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tablename'");
            $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $next = $data['Auto_increment'];
            echo $next;
```

However, it's not printing out the value... what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tablename'" );
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql , ARRAY_A );
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I ended up doing the following:

```
$next = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
                FROM information_schema.TABLES
                WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'
                AND TABLE_NAME = 'tableName'"));
```

I wanted to get that auto_increment value isolated, so this worked best for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use following code succesfully

```
$table = $wpdb->prefix.'YourTableName';
$query = "SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourDataBaseName' AND TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName'";
$id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($query));
```